# Not return value from custom helper

Tags: node.js

I have problem with my node.js helper. My helper send post request to payu API, API return access_token which i need. If receive access_token then i need return him.

My code:

```
module.exports = {
    createPaymentToken: async () => {
        const response =  await request({
                method: 'POST',
                json: false,
                url: payuAuthUrl,
                form: {
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                    'client_id': payuMerchantID,
                    'client_secret': payuSecret,
                }
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
              if (response) {
                const result = (JSON.parse(body));
                const token = result.access_token;
                return token;
             }
           }
        );
    },
```

When i add console.log(token) before return token, then i see my access_token. The problem is when I want to pass this token to the controller, i.e. it reaches me undefined.

My controller

```
  testPayment: async (req, res) => {
        var result = await payuHelper.createPaymentToken();
        res.send({
            result
        });
    },
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The `createPaymentToken` function does not return anything. The return statement is returning value to the scope of its caller and its caller is the request function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement was placed inside callback, so the `createPaymentToken` function doesn't return anything, just fix your code like sample below:

```
module.exports = {
    createPaymentToken: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                    method: 'POST',
                    json: false,
                    url: payuAuthUrl,
                    form: {
                        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                        'client_id': payuMerchantID,
                        'client_secret': payuSecret,
                    }
                },
                function (error, response, body) {
                  if (error) {
                    return reject(error)
                  }
                  if (response) {
                    const result = (JSON.parse(body));
                    const token = result.access_token;
                    return resolve(token);
                 }
               }
            );
        })
    },
}
```

[Promise document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I did it in a similar way but I was asked Promis {pending} :) Thank you very much for your help, of course it works great